# Laravel Yajra DataTable datecolumn is not orderable and not searcheable

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datatable, eloquent-relationship, yajra-datatable

I've got a `User` model and a `Membership` model, they have a one to one ralationship.

In the datatable i'm passing the `expiration` date of the `Membership` model with some `User` info.
However i cannot order that column nor i can search in it.

My current `query()` function inside the controller looks like this:

```php
    public function query(Request $request){

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $model = User::with('membership');

            return DataTables::eloquent($model)
                ->addColumn('membership', function (User $user){
                    $expiration = Carbon::parse($user->membership['expiration']);
                    return $expiration;
                })
                ->toJson();
        }

        return view('users', [
            'PageName' => 'Users',
        ]);
    }
```

Meanwhile the script in my view looks like this:

```php
<script>
        $('#usersTable').ready(function () {
            $('table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            language: {
                processing: '<span>Processing</span>',
            },
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ route('users.query') }}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'username', name: 'username' },
                { data: 'membership', name: 'membership' },
                { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
                { data: 'actions', name: 'actions', orderable: false, searcheable: false },
            ],
        });
        });
    </script>
```

I have no idea on what's wrong and hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: you are trying to search from datatable?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to use the search function of the datatable itself

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error, it was in the `query()` function inside the controller. This is the correct code:

```php
    public function query(Request $request){

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $model = User::with('membership');

            return DataTables::eloquent($model)
                ->addColumn('membership', function (User $user){
                    return $user->membership->expiration
                })
                ->toJson();
        }

        return view('users', [
            'PageName' => 'Users',
        ]);
    }
```